# How to compile my Android app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm going through the Android tutorials, and I'm having trouble with one of the resource IDs.

In the `res\menu\main.xml` file, I have an `action_entry` defined in the menu tag as follows:

```
    <item
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable:ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string:action_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

In the `res\values\string.xml` file, I have the following string defined:

```
<string name="action_search">Search</string>
```

Finally, in the `OnOptionsItemSelected()` function, I have the following code that references that ID:

```
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                //openSearch();
                return true;
            ...
         }
```

According to an earlier lesson in the tutorial, the @+id means that the ID will be generated when the app is compiled, so naturally I'm expecting the `case R.id.action_search:` line to be in error until then; however, when I go to run the app (which I thought would trigger a compile whenever necessary), I get an error message stating that my project contains errors that have to be fixed before running the app.

How do I force a compile of the app so that the ID is added to the generated file that contains the IDs in my project? Without an actual compile command, I'm kind of stuck in a catch-22 situation: I can't run the app until I fix the error, but to fix the error, I have to compile the app so that it generates the ID, and the only way I know to do that is to run the app. Alternatively, how do I make the IDE generate the new ID so that the app compiles when I run it?

Comment: Where is your `main.xml` file placed?

Comment: That's the one in the res\menu folder.

Comment: Look at Package Explorer in eclipse. There should be an X in a red circle on any file which has an error in it. Fix each one and then rebuild.

Comment: The only x in a red circle is on my MainActivity.java file, and in the listing, it's right square on that ID that's in error. According to everything I've read so far (here and in the Android tutorial), building the app should generate the ID in the R.java file, but I can't build the app, because Eclipse won't let me due to the error. I need to be able to build the app so that the ID gets generated and, thus, fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should automatically update the `R.java` file, even if you are using `@+id/`. However, it will not automatically update if there is an issue in one of your XML files.

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/action_search"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
  android:title="@string/action_search"
  app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Try this.

Comment: I'm still getting the error regarding the ID in the main Java file.

Comment: Did you check and make sure that all other XML files also don't have problems? If everything is good, then your R.java file *should* update, although in the past I have experienced issues where it doesn't even without any XML issues so it can be kinda tricky to figure out. I'm not to sure of a good solution for that...my solution has been to just mess around a bit retyping/saving and hoping that it "catches" and updates R. But as Sarge Borsch points out, there may be a better method.

Comment: Once I corrected the XML file with the above code, the issue wasn't with the XML files. It was with the main Java file that was trying to reference the ID. Commenting out the code that referenced the ID and saving allowed the ID to be generated; and then I could uncomment the Java code again without getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The String names are in `R.string` class, not in `R.id`.

Edit: OK, you have also an ID with the same name, then it should find it... try cleaning/rebuilding the project.

Also, if there are any errors in XML files, you have to fix them to get the generated Java files.

Comment: That's what my question is all about. How _do_ I rebuild the project so I can get out of this logjam?

Comment: The Project tab in Eclipse has option to Clean and Build Automatically.